# Как задать вертикальный Scroll для Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Я начинающий в WPF. До этого все время работал только с WinForms. На главном окне есть несколько элементов, один из которых DataGrid.
[image]

Как видно из рисунка, элемент DataGrid не умещается в Grid. При всем моем старании я не могу вызвать вертикальный Scroll у Grid.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="cokoDB_WPF.MainWindow"
        Title="База данных" Height="870.074" Width="1016.94">
    <Grid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="63*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="36*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,431,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="234" Width="625"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Что делать?

Comment: Разбейте свой `Grid` еще и на строки с помощью [Grid.RowDefenitions][1]. И старайтесь не задавать явно высоту и ширину контролов, используйте контейнеры

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Я сделал RowDefenitions и ColumnDefenitions, как теперь вставить туда свой Grid?

Comment: Колонки в вашем случае не нужны, просто замените

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="63*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="36*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
на

 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinitionsWidth="63*"/>
            <RowDefinitionsWidth="2*"/>
            <RowDefinitionsWidth="36*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

И Grid.Column="0" на Grid.Row="2" где значение колонки, зависит от того каким по списку, будет Ваш элемент, нумерация начинается с 0.